# How to register service worker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I can not register a service worker. The file is located along with the index.js and app.js. I get next errors

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Registration failed TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A 
bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

****** 
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('`load`', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js', { scope:'./' })
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Registration completed successfully',registration);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Registration failed', error);
            })
     })}
```

Comment: It not only have to be along side `index.js` and `app.js`, it has to be in the root of your application. so if it happens your `index.js` or `app.js` are in a folder say `js`, it wont work. just put `serviceWorker.js` in the same directory as `index.html` and please run it in a server

Comment: Add this as an answer, it works. But I can not understand why it is such an arrangement that is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not only have to be along side index.js and app.js, it has to be in the root of your application. so if it happens your index.js or app.js are in a folder say js, it wont work. just put serviceWorker.js in the same directory as index.html and please run it in a server

Why is this?
I am not an expert at this, but I know service workers are used to serve all your files on an offline scenerio. If you put it as a relative path, it's going to be tricky to map to all other files outside.

This is not a rule though, you can somehow find a way to put your serviceWorker in some subfolder, but I personally don't consider this a best practice

Comment: Suppose I have 10 service workers, from the point of view of semantics it is not nice to place them along with the .html file. It is better to make a folder of service workers and point the way to it. But this method does not work.

Comment: No matter how many service workers you write, only one will be registered by the browser, and the moment you register another worker, it replaces the previous one. This in turn will lead you to write only one good service worker. If you are going to need 10 service workers, then there is definitely something wrong with your code/design

Comment: Would like to emphasize "it has to be in the root of your application" which vin my case was the root of my Amazon EC2 web server.  

I worked on this for a full week and andylamax is the only person who has said anything about the service worker's location requirement.  Thank you Andy!

Answer (score 0):

Service Workers are used to cache assets and other files so that in case of slow network or the user being offline results could be rendered on the screen. This results in better user experience.

For details you might want to visit:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

This is done at the index.js and if you are using latest CRA version you just need to modify the last line from `serviceWorker.unregister();` to `serviceWorker.register();`